# Why ScriptDb query result object is different

Tags: javascript, database, google-apps-script

```
function myFunction() {
  var item = {};
  item = {id:'myId', rules: {1:'rule1', 2:'rule2'}};
  Logger.log(item);  // {id=myId, rules={2=rule2, 1=rule1}}
  Logger.log(item.rules[1]);  // rule1

  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  db.save(item);

  var result = db.query({id:'myId'});
  item = result.next();
  Logger.log(item);  // {id=myId, rules={2=rule2, 1=rule1}}
  Logger.log(item.rules[1]);  // undefined, why?

}
```

Expecting the last log to return the value "rule1" like in the original object.
Why is it now undefined?

Comment: One for the issue tracker. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I can't see any example in the doc that show you can have an object as key value... did you ?

Comment: I saw the date obj restriction, but I may just be thinking about the storage design wrong with what I want to do here.

Comment: I think that your number key gets parsed into a string key, have you tried `item.rules["1"]` ?

Comment: so storing `item` with `rules:{"1":"rule1"}` still does not work when retrieving the rule value with `item.rules["1"]`, but `rules:{"one":"rule1"}` does return the expected result when using `item.rules["one"]`.  i'm trying to use the numerical or string digit key for my case though and the parsing below did work.

Answer (score 1):

A strange case, it may be a bug.

With the following code can get what you need:

```js
...
item = JSON.parse(item.toJson());
Logger.log(item);  // {id=myId, rules={2=rule2, 1=rule1}}
Logger.log(item.rules[1]);  // rule1
...
```

Comment: which would mean - as I suspected in the other comment - that the value can't be an object itself...

Comment: A little more rare the case! [ScriptDB: Saving and Loading Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db): `ScriptDB stores all data as maps — that is, as JavaScript objects composed of key-value pairs. The values in a map can be strings, numbers, arrays, or other nested maps, but not methods or Date objects.`

Comment: thx!  Wondering if I should be storing each rule separately as their own object instead.

Comment: @Sergeinsas the value can be an object itself, there's no such restriction.

Comment: Thanks Henrique, Yes, I saw the doc now... That said it seems to "loose" its object properties in the process... As @ScampMichael said, this is probably one for the issue tracker.// btw, welcome back ;-) we were missing you !

Comment: The issue with this nested object `rules`, is that it has numeric keys. Replace `1` and `2` with `a` and `b` and it's going to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative route for storing and filtering results with a numerical value instead of with a numerical key.

```
function myFunction() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var item1 = {id:'myId', rule:{num:1, details:'rule1'}};
  var item2 = {id:'myId', rule:{num:2, details:'rule2'}};

  var saveResults = db.saveBatch([item1, item2], false);

  var results = db.query({id:'myId'});

  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var item = results.next();
    if (item.rule.num == 1) 
      Logger.log(item.rule.details);  // rule1
  }
}
```